# Video.js: How to display captions only on custom TextTrackDisplay element, not on top of video

Tags: video.js, caption

I'm attempting to display Video.js captions on a custom DOM element, outside of the video playing. This works as intended and below are snippets showing this.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to disable captions appearing also on top of the video too. Is there a way to disable captions appearing/showing on top of the video and only in the TextTrackDisplay element?

Any setting in the caption options (`addRemoteTextTrack(options)`) and `textTrackSettings.setValues()` seems to affect both on-video and custom captions.

```js
let captionOption = {
    kind: 'captions',
    srclang: 'en',
    label: 'English',
    src: subURL,
    mode: 'showing',
};
```

```js
connectTextTracks = (player) => {
    const TextTrackDisplay = videojs.getComponent('TextTrackDisplay');
    const textTrackDisplay = new TextTrackDisplay(player);
    subtitleDiv.appendChild(textTrackDisplay.el());
}
```

```js
player.ready(function () {
    player.addRemoteTextTrack(captionOption);
    const tracks = player.remoteTextTracks();
    console.log(tracks.length); // print out greater than 0 if captions exists

    var settings = this.textTrackSettings;

    settings.setValues({
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        backgroundOpacity: '1',
        edgeStyle: 'uniform',
    });
    settings.updateDisplay();

    connectTextTracks(player);
});
```

[image: Video.js - Custom TextTrackDisplay element]

Comment: What happens if you try to 'hide' the on-screen captions, by setting font-color and backgrond color both to black?

Comment: I find your issue interesting! (I'm curious to understand what CSS you used  to move your new captions so far below the viewer.) Do you have your full implementation out somewhere that I could see it?  (My code so far is here: https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Double-caps/) Thx.

Comment: @david I actually just created a new `TextTrackDisplay` and added that to the DOM. See here for full implementation: https://codepen.io/avtconnect/pen/poOvEyj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

A better way to disable on-video captions is to set the `textTrackDisplay` to `false` in the player options:

```js
const player = videojs(videoEl, {
    //... other vjs options
    textTrackDisplay : false //Disable the textTrackDisplay component
});
```

See the full discussion here: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/discussions/8064
Example pen here: https://codepen.io/avtconnect/pen/dyqMJQN?editors=1010

Additionally, to avoid errors in console, `new TextTrackDisplay` should include options:

```js
new TextTrackDisplay(player, {playerOptions : {}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just hiding the on-video text track display, before creating a new `TextTrackDisplay`, like so:

```js
// First hide main text track display (on-video)
const mainTextTrackDisplay = player.getChild('TextTrackDisplay');
mainTextTrackDisplay.setAttribute("hidden", true);

// Add new text track display
const TextTrackDisplay = videojs.getComponent('TextTrackDisplay');
const newTextTrackDisplay = new TextTrackDisplay(player);
const newTextTrackDisplayEl = newTextTrackDisplay.el();

// Append new text track display to subdiv element
const subDiv = document.querySelector("#subdiv");
subDiv.append(newTextTrackDisplayEl);
```

Full example here:
https://codepen.io/avtconnect/pen/poOvEyj